# How to change targeted texts font color, based off the day of the week?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a table row, where each cell has visible text that changes color based on the day of the week. I set the functions into each cell with the corresponding day and color. I cna't seem to get it to work correctly though. I can't tell if I am missing something. Please help?

```
<tr>
  <td><script>
    function(){
      var theday = new Date().getDays();                    
      if theday == 1 {
        document.write('S').style.color = #FF0000;
      }
      else:
        document.write('S').style.color = #FFFFFF;
      }}
  </td></script>                    
</tr>
```

Current code:

```
         <tr>
            <td><script>
                Date.prototype.getWeekDay = function(){
                    var theday = new Date().getDays();                    
                    if (theday == 1) {
                        document.write('S').style.color = #FF0000;
                    }
                    else
                        document.write('S').style.color = #FFFFFF;
                    }}
            </script></td>
```

I should've mention that I am using Mozilla Firefox as my primary browser.
Current Edit:

```
        <tr>
            <td id='sun'></td>
            <td id='mon'></td>
            <td id='tue'></td>
            <td id='wed'></td>
            <td id='thr'></td>
            <td id='fri'></td>
            <td id='sat'></td>              
        </tr>

<script>
window.onload = function(){
   var theday = new Date().getDay();  
   var color = theday == 1 ? '#FF0000' : '#FFFFFF';
   var color = theday == 2 ? '#FF7F00' : '#FFFFFF';
   var color = theday == 3 ? '#FFFF00' : '#FFFFFF';
   var color = theday == 4 ? '#00FF00' : '#FFFFFF';
   var color = theday == 5 ? '#0000FF' : '#FFFFFF';
   var color = theday == 6 ? '#2E2B5F' : '#FFFFFF';
   var color = theday == 7 ? '#8B00FF' : '#FFFFFF';
   document.getElementById('sun').style.backgroundColor = color;
   document.getElementById('mon').style.backgroundColor = color;
   document.getElementById('tue').style.backgroundColor = color;
   document.getElementById('wed').style.backgroundColor = color;
   document.getElementById('thr').style.backgroundColor = color;
   document.getElementById('fri').style.backgroundColor = color;
   document.getElementById('sat').style.backgroundColor = color;
  }
</script>
```

Console Message:

Uncaught TypeError: (new Date()).getDays is not a function

Corrected typo in code from .getDays > .getDay

Updated code:

```
        <tr>
            <td id='sun'>S</td>
            <td id='mon'>M</td>
            <td id='tue'>Ts</td>
            <td id='wed'>W</td>
            <td id='thr'>Th</td>
            <td id='fri'>F</td>
            <td id='sat'>S</td>             
        </tr>

<script>
window.onload = function(){
   var theday = new Date().getDay();  
   var c1 = theday == 1 ? '#FF0000' : '#FFFFFF';
   var c2 = theday == 2 ? '#FF7F00' : '#FFFFFF';
   var c3 = theday == 3 ? '#FFFF00' : '#FFFFFF';
   var c4 = theday == 4 ? '#00FF00' : '#FFFFFF';
   var c5 = theday == 5 ? '#0000FF' : '#FFFFFF';
   var c6 = theday == 6 ? '#2E2B5F' : '#FFFFFF';
   var c7 = theday == 7 ? '#8B00FF' : '#FFFFFF';
   document.getElementById('sun').style.color = c1;
   document.getElementById('mon').style.color = c2;
   document.getElementById('tue').style.color = c3;
   document.getElementById('wed').style.color = c4;
   document.getElementById('thr').style.color = c5;
   document.getElementById('fri').style.color = c6;
   document.getElementById('sat').style.color = c7;
  }
</script>
```

Still not updating the font like I wanted it too.

NEW UPDATE:

```
        <tr>
            <td id='sun'>S</td>
            <td id='mon'>M</td>
            <td id='tue'>Ts</td>
            <td id='wed'>W</td>
            <td id='thr'>Th</td>
            <td id='fri'>F</td>
            <td id='sat'>S</td>             
        </tr>

<script>
window.onload = function(){
   var theday = new Date().getDay(); 
   var c1 = theday == 0 ? '#FF0000' : '#999999';
   var c2 = theday == 1 ? '#FF7F00' : '#999999';
   var c3 = theday == 2 ? '#FFFF00' : '#999999';
   var c4 = theday == 3 ? '#00FF00' : '#999999';
   var c5 = theday == 4 ? '#0000FF' : '#999999';
   var c6 = theday == 5 ? '#2E2B5F' : '#999999';
   var c7 = theday == 6 ? '#8B00FF' : '#999999';
   document.getElementById('sun').style.color = c1;
   document.getElementById('mon').style.color = c2;
   document.getElementById('tue').style.color = c3;
   document.getElementById('wed').style.color = c4;
   document.getElementById('thr').style.color = c5;
   document.getElementById('fri').style.color = c6;
   document.getElementById('sat').style.color = c7;
  }
</script>
```

This worked! Thank you!

Comment: change it to `if (theday == 1)` and `else`. There must be ERROR in console.

Comment: After making these changes, this is the error I get from console:
Uncaught SyntaxError: private fields are not currently supported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<table cellspacing='10' id='calendarTable'>
    <tr class='header'>
        <td id='sun'>Sunday</td>
        <td id='mon'>Monday</td>
        <td id='tue'>Tuesday</td>
        <td id='wed'>Wednesday</td>
        <td id='thr'>Thursday</td>
        <td id='fri'>Friday</td>
        <td id='sat'>Saturday</td>              
    </tr>
    </table>

    <script>
   var theday = new Date().getDay();  
           var colors = {
              'sun' : '#206AE6', //sunday
              'mon' : '#cccccc', //moday
              'tue' : '#999999', //tuesday
              'wed' : '#666666', //wednesday
              'thu' : '#333333', //thurs
              'fri' : '#000000', //fri
              'sat' : '#ff0000', //saturday
           };

        window.onload = function(){
           var headerrow = document.querySelectorAll('#calendarTable tr.header td');
           headerrow.forEach(el => {
               el.style.color = colors[el.id];
          })
        }


     </script>
```

Comment: This is the error message I am getting with this edit:
Uncaught TypeError: (new Date()).getDays is not a function

Comment: sorry @JustinBache - a typo. `new Date().getDay()` I corrected it above and put it in a snippet that you could test.

Comment: I keep getting encoding error on firefox. The font is defaulting to the secondary color. definately think I'm getting closer to my desired answer though

Comment: @JustinBache - I updated my code to reflect. Put your colors in an array and then just reference them with `theday` which is always going to be a number, 0 for sunday, 1 for monday... and so on.

Comment: @JustinBache - note this new approach. Assign all your colors first in an object, then match the id of the table cell to the object reference. I did it through a loop.

Comment: Thank you for the help. The final update gave me the desired outcome I was looking for, although your submit definitely is cleaner looking. I will likely utilize your answer. Again Thank you.